# How to compare if a substring exist inside an array in PostgreSQL query?

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql

example

```
const testString = "bmw,honda,mercedes,audi"

const testArray = ['renault', 'mini', 'honda', 'dacia']
```

how to check if at least on element from `testString` exist on `testArray`

tried **string_to_array()**

Answer (score 0):

There's no SQL in the question; however, if *testString* and *testArray* are of types text and  array of text, respectively, then `string_to_array(testString, ',') && testArray` achieve the desired result.